# How can I install haskell-hunit?

Tags: installation, package-management, apt, haskell

I'm running 11.10 (amd64). I see there's this package:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/oneiric/haskell-hunit

However:

```
$ sudo apt-get install haskell-hunit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package haskell-hunit
```

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [*source* package](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkg_basics.en.html):

> ## 7.13 How do I install a source package?
>
> Debian source packages can't actually be "installed", they are just unpacked in whatever directory you want to build the binary packages they produce.
>
> Source packages are distributed on most of the same mirrors where you can obtain the binary packages. If you set up your APT's sources.list(5) to include the appropriate "deb-src" lines, you'll be able to easily download any source packages by running
>
> ```
>  apt-get source foo
> ```
>
> To help you in actually building the source package, Debian source package provide the so-called build-dependencies mechanism. This means that the source package maintainer keeps a list of other packages that are required to build their package. To see how this is useful, run
>
> ```
>  apt-get build-dep foo
> ```
>
> before building the source.

So you can't actually "install" it. However, there are binary packages 
built from it:

- [libghc-hunit-dev[image: Install libghc-hunit-dev]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libghc-hunit-dev)
  Haskell unit testing framework for GHC
- [libghc-hunit-doc[image: Install libghc-hunit-doc]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libghc-hunit-doc)
  Haskell unit testing framework for GHC; documentation
- [libghc-hunit-proof[image: Install libghc-hunit-proof]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libghc-hunit-proof)
  Haskell unit testing framework for GHC; profiling libraries

One of them should contain what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I typically install only Haskell Platform and GHC from apt and then install everything else through Cabal. Haskell dependencies are a bit messy and many times require updating packages much sooner than Ubuntu's 6 month release cycle. Cabal install's everything into `~/.cabal/` which is nice because if things get screwed up, you can delete it and start over. I think most of the Haskell community works this way from what I've gathered on IRC.